# Prevent slow INNER JOIN in Django model calls when unnecessary

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Is it possible to prevent Django from using INNER JOIN in SQL relationship queries when unnecessary?

I have the two tables:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, db_index=True)
```

The author table has more than 50 million rows, which makes requests such getting all the books of one author, `Book.objects.filter(author_id='John Smith')`, incredibly slow (about 20 sec). However, when I use raw SQL to achieve the same result, the query is almost instant: `SELECT * FROM books WHERE author_id='John Smith';`.

Using result.query I have found that Django is slower because it runs a INNER JOIN query on the entire table:

```
SELECT books.title, books.author_id FROM books INNER JOIN authors 
    ON (books.author_id = authors.name) WHERE books.author_id = 'John Smith';
```

Is there a way to make Django avoid the INNER JOIN in cases such as this when it isn't necessary?

I would like to avoid using raw SQL queries if at all possible as this database structure is highly simplified.

Comment: Use select_related:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: @petkostas Thank you for your input! However, that still doesn't avoid the INNER JOIN.

Comment: Do you access the author information in the template or other parts of your flow?

Comment: Can you try with defer? 
`Book.objects.filter(author_id='John Smith').defer('author')` and see how this performs?

Comment: @petkostas Defer is equally slow and the raises the error: `MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Book -- it returned 6217!` (using the exact command you suggested with filter).

Comment: @petkostas No, I only access the information from the backend.

Comment: What version of django are you running? I'm on 1.5.1 and I ran a similar query (filter on ForeignKey to a model whose pk is a charField) and it did not do an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Interesting, haven't ever had the need to query only the one model breaking the relation.
Could you try:
`Book.objects.filter(author_id='John Smith').defer('author').all()` or:
`Book.objects.filter(author='John Smith').all()`

Comment: @pcoronel I believe the Join is performed because he is using `author_id` id is a remote field not the field on the model.

Comment: @petkostas defer() still throws the error. Omitting `_id` runs the same SQL query as with it.

Comment: @petkostas remote field?? `author_id` is the column name in the database. I reproduced the conditions of his query, the only difference between you and me is 1.5.1 vs 1.5.4, and that you have `db_index`es on your fields.

Comment: @pcoronel Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: `ON (books.author_id = authors.name)` Using a char(50) or varchar(50) column as a PK and using it as a FK is not recommended. Use a numerical key instead. (and add a UNIQUE constravt on the name field)

Comment: @pcoronel sorry it was my mistake.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you, you're right. However, I am in a situation where I cannot change the database layout, so that's why I'm asking to avoid the inner join.

Comment: I made a quick check in a older project, this is something like realestate, the HouseModel has a foreign key to town, my query does not return a JOIN:
`test = HouseModel.objects.filter(town=1).all()`
`print test`
`SELECT ... WHERE "properties_housemodel"."town_id" = 1`
I ommited a few of the fields as they are not relevant...

Comment: I don't know if this was changed in Django versions, or if this is because of the way you handle primary keys in it...

Comment: By any chance, do you use a custom Manager?

Comment: @petkostas Thank you for your help. I don't have a custom Manager, no. However, when checking I realized that I have a Meta class in the Book model with the attribute `ordering = ['author', 'title']`. When I disabled that, the JOIN was omitted from the query.

Comment: @petkostas As I wouldn't have found the problem without you, I'll accept it if you post the answer. Otherwise I'll close the question.

Comment: Thank you :) I believe you should answer your own question, I didn't do much :)

Comment: Do you know the reason why ordering caused an inner join? I don't quite understand why it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution turned out to be **removing** a `class Meta` option:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    (...)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['author', 'title']
```

Comment: Thanks to petkostas and pcoronel for their help.